# Django dynamic form for multiple choice selection

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Django app where I ask users to select amongst multiple choices of cities on an html template. The choices of cities are based on distinct instances of cities in the database table. Since the total number of cities is over 100, what I’d like to do instead is to give the user the option to select all cities (so they don’t have to manually select 100+ cities) or to select individual cities using a multiplechoicefield if they want some subset of the 100+ cities. How can I go about implementing this in Django?

Here’s my code for what I am currently doing:

forms.py

```
 class FilterCityForm(forms.Form):
    q = listing.objects.all().values('Address_locality').distinct().order_by('Address_locality')
    CITY_CHOICES = [[x['Address_locality'],x['Address_locality']] for x in q]
    city = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CITY_CHOICES, required=True, widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size':'30'}))
```

views.py

```
def main_select_cities(request):
    form = FilterCityForm(request.POST or None)
    city_list = dict()
    if form.is_valid():
        city_list = form.cleaned_data.get("city")
        return process_cities(request, city_list)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'city_list': city_list,
    }
    return render(request, "0_select_cities.html", context)
```

The template

```
{% block content %}

<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>

        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <br><br>

        <h4>Select all the cities for which you would like to view listings</h4>    

                <form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form.as_p}}
                    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' type='submit' value='Show listings'/>

                </form>
                <br>
                <i> use ctrl or shift + click to select multiple options</i>
        </div>  

    </div>
</div> 

{% endblock %}
```